# Symfony2 : Multiple members zones with multiple entities and enabling switch_user

Tags: symfony

I'm very new to symfony2. I read every document found on symfony.com
and a bunch of other found on the web.

I'm still struggling with a -maybe- basic problem and probably very
common.

Here is the explanation in details:

- I have designed my databse to have 2 tables : member and webmaster
- Member will have some basic features on the public website to post
  items on the website (let say, like a forum)
- Member has only the role ROLE_USER
- Webmaster will have a access to a totally different zone, like a
  backend
- Webmaster has the role ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
  (and a few hove them will have ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN)

For now, this is very basic and I made it work using 2 differents
firewalls, each one using the corresponding entity provider.

But now, I want to implement the great switch user feature. The idea
here is to let webmaster connect as Member to see exactly what they
see.

After many tries, I can't make it work.

Can somebody help me to make it works?

I'm totally open to write some listener, extends the Symfony security
layer or something like that. I just can't find where to start and
which direction to take to do it greatly.

Thanks in advance